# Browser does not allow page refresh after Commit

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I am having a big problem here. I create a simple page and insert a form, a **createInsert** button and a **commit** button for example. I run this page and everything is fine. I create a new record, fill the form fields and then commit. In this moment if I press **F5** to reload the page, the browser asks me for confirmation "*To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.*" I don't understand why it has to repeat any action, I checked for dirty transactions after the commit operation and transactions are clean. If I move from this page to another and back to first it works fine, F5 refreshes without problem.

If I have a table with multiple rows and I update first row for example, and then click the third row and then perform a refresh (Confirm on above message), the third row will obtain the obtain all the information of the first row...

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like an ADF issue; your form is doing a `POST`, and the browser warns before repeating a `POST` - that's just normal behaviour. When you leave and come back you're doing a `GET`. Why are you hitting F5 at all though - doesn't your page redraw after the form submission include the changes you just made?

Comment: There is no specific reason for hitting F5, but this may be a user behavior and if that happens, like the scenario that I explained, my application may encounter some serious problems with its data.

Comment: Then you need to detect a duplicate POST in your back-end and ignore it, or do something [like the Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), so that a refresh will just do a GET. I have no idea if your stack has that capability built in or if it's something you'll need to design.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just found the error, I putted it in my answer. Maybe there is an ajax conflict or something like this. However making "partialSubmit=true" to buttons did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the real problem and solution to this. As I said reopening the page does not bring any problem, but only hitting F5 does. My 'submit' and 'commit' buttons had 'partialSubmit=false' which should perform a total page submit in this case. Apparently this is not "detected" by the browser when pressing F5 although submission is performed. Changing 'partialSubmit=true' to the buttons did the trick. Tung